# change event on the checkbox of views bulk operations

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I want to implement the change event on the check boxes of the views bulk operation.

I have a block view of bulk operations which displays fname and lname of the users.
I wrote the code in the views-view--vbo-signup--block-1.tpl.php and add two text boxes to the view.

Now I want when i select a row in the view its fname displays in the first text box and its lname displays in the 2nd text box.

Any idea about this???